# How to use a Postgres db on heroku with Axios and Vue?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, heroku, vuejs2, axios

I making a spa with Vue and want to deploy this on Heroku and provision a database with Postgres.

I managed to get the app to run on Heroku, with a node server. I added the db and the connection (in the same file) and it is working in production.
But I want to make the HTTP-request to de the db with Axios and test this locally before deployment. And this is where I'm stuck.

I've copied the DATABASE_URL the a .env, but still no access to the database. When I print the value to the console it is always undefined.

My server.js:

```
const express = require("express");
const serveStatic = require("serve-static");
const path = require("path");
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

// Connection to the database
const { Client } = require('pg');
const client = new Client({
  connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
  ssl: {
    rejectUnauthorized: false
  }
});
client.connect();
client.query('SELECT table_schema,table_name FROM information_schema.tables;', (err, res) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  for (let row of res.rows) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(row));
  }
  client.end();
});

//
const app = express();

//here we are configuring dist to serve app files
app.use("/", serveStatic(path.join(__dirname, "/dist")));

// this * route is to serve project on different page routes except root `/`
app.get(/.*/, function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "/dist/index.html"));
});

app.listen(port);
console.log(`app is listening on port: ${port}`);
```

UserService.js:

```
import axios from 'axios';

// the single Axios instance we use for calls
const apiClient = axios.create({
  //baseURL: 'http://localhost:5000',
  baseURL: process.env.DATABASE_URL, // with ssl?
  withCredentials: false, // this is the default
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
});

export default {
  /* with pagination */
  getUsers() {
    console.log(process.env.DATABASE_URL);
    return apiClient.get('/users');
  },
};
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "test-deploy-heroku",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "dns": "^0.2.2",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "pg": "^8.5.1",
    "pg-native": "^3.0.0",
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "vue-router": "^3.2.0",
    "vuetify": "^2.4.0",
    "vuex": "^3.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-prettier": "^6.0.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.3.1",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.2.2",
    "prettier": "^2.2.1",
    "sass": "^1.32.0",
    "sass-loader": "^10.0.0",
    "vue-cli-plugin-vuetify": "~2.3.1",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11",
    "vuetify-loader": "^1.7.0"
  }
}
```

I copied the config vars to my local .env file

```
heroku config:get CONFIG-VAR-NAME -s  >> .env
```

And the started the process with

```
heroku local
```

But I still can not connect to the db with axios.

I searched all over, but didn't find an answer.

Comment: Please do **not** post code as images. See here for more details why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551

Comment: Ok thx, I will pay attention to this.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add ***require('dotenv').config()*** to the top of your server.js file

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') require('dotenv').config()
```